# Does exposing a server IP address pose a threat?

Tags: security

Just noticed a site I'm working on exposes the server IP address within a JS file. Could this pose a threat to the site and/or server?

Comment: do you know what a DNS is?

Comment: Not a programming question but everyone knows the IP since they're already communicating with the server

Comment: Pinging the website exposes the IP address anyways.

Comment: Perhaps he does not talk about the ip of the server that hosts the js file?

Comment: You mean local server IP which is behind NAT? Or the hosting server but you have dedicated IP for the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file simply uses or states the IP of the server where your website is running it will not pose a threat. Your domain name points to the same IP address anyway, as this is the publicly known address for machines to identify themselves (just to simplify it slightly). So your IP is already known to the world wide web. Otherwise nobody would be able to visit your website.

Comment: Yes, the JS file states th IP of the server from where the website is running. Thanks for your response. My concern was that some hosting companies charge to make the server IP anonymous, so I thought if they were doing that, could it be that there is a security risk with showing it.